# How to set a primary key in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I want to set **one of my fields as primary key**. I am using [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) as my NoSQL.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

`_id` field is reserved for primary key in mongodb, and that should be a unique value. If you don't set anything to `_id` it will automatically fill it with "MongoDB Id Object". But you can put any unique info into that field.

Additional info: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON

Hope it helps.

Comment: This indeed doesn't answer to `how to set one of my fields as primary key`, ex: i want user_email as key in user collections, but how to set that field as key and unique

Comment: How does this answers the question??

Comment: The _id field is the default index and needs to be unique. Therefore, place the data that is your unique constraint into that field. 
 (https://docs.mongodb.com/master/indexes/#default-id-index)

Comment: let us say I do add something myself to _id. Do I get to choose the data type or will it always be String (or object?)

Answer (score 31):

In mongodb _id field is reserved for primary key. Mongodb use an internal ObjectId value if you don't define it in your object and also create an index to ensure performance.

But you can put your own unique value for _id and Mongodb will use it instead of making one for you. And even if you want to use multiple field as primary key you can use an object:

```
{ _id : { a : 1, b: 1} }
```

Just be careful when using object as ids, the order of keys (a and b in the example) matters, if you swap them, it is considered a different id.

Comment: This is interesting.  Any reason I couldn't use this on an "archive" collection to store old versions of my documents in another colllection?  `{ _id: { _id: ...object id..., version: 4 }`

Comment: @Robert _id field are indexed and kept in memory, so basically you are keeping all documents of that collection in memory.

Comment: Well I'll trust Mongo DB to manage the "working set" of what gets put into memory.  I was a bit more concerned about key constraints but I found my answer here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Index-Key-Limit

Answer (score 28):

The other way is to create `Indexes` for your collection and  make sure that they are unique.

You can find more on the following [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/)

I actually find this pretty simple and easy to implement.

Comment: "The unique constraint on indexes ensures that only one document can have a value for a field in a collection. For sharded collections these unique indexes cannot enforce uniqueness because insert and indexing operations are local to each shard"  --https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections/

Answer (score 24):

If you thinking like RDBMS, you can't create primary key. Default primary key is _id.
But you can create [Unique Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/). Example is bellow.

```
db.members.createIndex( { "user_id": 1 }, { unique: true } )

db.members.insert({'user_id':1,'name':'nanhe'})

db.members.insert({'name':'kumar'})

db.members.find();
```

Output is bellow :

{ "_id" : ObjectId("577f9cecd71d71fa1fb6f43a"), "user_id" : 1, "name" : "nanhe" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("577f9d02d71d71fa1fb6f43b"), "name" : "kumar" }

When you try to insert same user_id mongodb throws a write error.

```
db.members.insert({'user_id':1,'name':'aarush'})
```

WriteResult({
"nInserted" : 0,
"writeError" : {
"code" : 11000,
"errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: student.members index: user_id_1 dup key: { : 1.0 }"
}
})

Answer (score 12):

Simple you can use

```
db.collectionName.createIndex({urfield:1},{unique:true});
```

Answer (score 7):

One way of achieving this behaviour is by setting the value to `_id` (which is reserved for a primary key in MongoDB) field based on the custom fields you want to treat as primary key.
i.e. If I want `employee_id` as the primary key then at the time of creating document in MongoDB; assign `_id` value same as that of `employee_id`.

Comment: it's redundant. just use _id

Answer (score 5):

This is the syntax of creating primary key

> db.< collection >.createIndex( < key and index type specification>, {
>   unique: true } )

Let's take that our database have collection named **student** and it's document have key named **student_id** which we need to make a primary key. Then the command should be like below.

```
db.student.createIndex({student_id:1},{unique:true})
```

You can check whether this **student_id** set as primary key by trying to add duplicate value to the **student** collection.

prefer this document for further informations  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#create-a-unique-index

Answer (score 2):

[MongoDB > Tutorial > Create an auto incrementing field - Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130803163812/http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

You can also check this link and auto-increment the `_id` field.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Link is now broken, thus this answer is useless

Comment: Downvoted, because the page now redirects to: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/ which mentions neither "auto" nor "increment".

Comment: The link is broken as suggested in other comments. I updated the link and now it points to a snapshot of the page from 2013 Aug on The Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Mongo on Meteor, you can use `_ensureIndex`:

```
CollectionName._ensureIndex({field:1 }, {unique: true});
```