# MongoDB: Is it possible to set the ID?

Tags: c#, mongodb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set primary key in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298963/how-to-set-primary-key-in-mongodb)

As I understood _id is generated by mongodb. Is there any way to set it manually? And if so, how to do it using C# driver?

Comment: @Filburt: I change my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find answer by myself. For C# driver it is enough to give the name `Id` or `_id` to desired property, and not to have `ObjectId` type property in your class. Then inside driver somehow decide that this property is `_id` for your data in mongodb.

Comment: I'm using string type for the property and it is null(in mongo). Can you share your code.
 public string _id  { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can generate an ObjectID at the client side. Every client library should provide a way to that. Here's how it is in ruby driver

```
require 'mongo'
oid = BSON::ObjectId.new
```

But the `_id` field doesn't have to be an ObjectId. It can be anything (except for array). You can provide your own value when inserting the document and mongo will happily accept it.