# Checking if record exists in MongoDB

Tags: python, performance, mongodb, pymongo

I'm building a MongoDB database and the problem is that I want to avoid duplicate entries. At the moment I'm doing this (inserting document only after checking if entry doesn't exist):

```
from pymongo import Connection 
import pandas as pd
from time import strftime
from collections import OrderedDict

connection = Connection()
db = connection.mydb 
collection = db.mycollection

data = pd.read_csv("data/myfile.csv", parse_dates=[2,5])

for i in range(len(data)):
    if(collection.find({ "id":     data.ix[0],                         \
                         "date1":  data.ix[i, 2].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), \
                         "date2":  data.ix[i, 5].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), \
                         "number": int(data.ix[i, 6]),                 \
                         "type":   data.ix[i, 7]}).count() == 0):
        collection.insert(here goes what I'd like to insert)
```

Which does work fine, but this already has significant performance issues (with just ~100Mb of data), as doing `find()` every time seems to slow things down significantly.

Is there a way to speed things up? Maybe I'm doing it fundamentally wrong?
I need to avoid duplicates only on a certain set of fields, not all of them (i.e., there is also "number2", which can be different, but I still want to have it as duplicate if all other fields match).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-unique) on the fields you are searching (mongo shell syntax):

```
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({_id:1, date1:1, date2:1, number:1, type:1}, {unique: true});
```

And capture the constraint violation exception (and ignore it if appropriate) when duplicates are inserted.

Typically this should increase performance as duplicates checking is done by an index lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Checking before inserting is not good way to prevent it. To prevent duplication of keys , use primary key. see [how to set a primary key in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298963/how-to-set-a-primary-key-in-mongodb)

Also if it's not good for you , at least add [mongo index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/)

The best way to solve this (I think) will be to generate key from all the field that are relevant  and then do 1 of the 2 :

1. Check on that key, which if will be index - will be faster
2. Make this key your primary key, and the insert will fail

Comment: you don't have to have something be a primary key to have a unique index on it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do an update() operation with the Upsert flag, see [Update Operations with the Upsert Flag](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/create/#crud-create-update).

Also there is already a built in id in MongoDB named "_id", so you can use it if you want.
Below is how it would look like:

```
collection.update(
    { "_id": ObjectID(data.ix[0]),
      "date1": data.ix[i, 2].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    }, 
    { "_id": ObjectID(data.ix[0]),
      "date1": data.ix[i, 2].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    },
    True
    )
```

Comment: yeah, I think I missed the question (which was speeding things up). Maybe this can just serve as an additional info that there is an upsert operation that can replace find() + insert(). If you guys think this will just confuse things, I can just delete this answer :)

Comment: I do think an upsert is related - it's the answer to the "find the document, if you do update it, if you don't insert it" but I think that's different from the initial problem stated (if it exists he doesn't want to do anything)...